# How to clip a triangular view from a rectangular view in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want view like below image:-
[desired view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nt6.png)
I am using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to archives this below code:-

```
     UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
//    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
//    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(_pendingView.frame.origin.x, _pendingView.frame.origin.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_pendingView.frame.origin.x+15, _pendingView.frame.origin.y+15)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_pendingView.frame.origin.x, _pendingView.frame.origin.y+30)];
    [path closePath];

//    [path fill ]; 
//    [path stroke];
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    shapeLayer.frame = _pendingView.bounds;
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    self.pendingView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
   // [self.pendingView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

but i am unable to achieve. View appear without Clipping and background colour of view.

**P.S :- pendingview is a view.**

**AS PER @inderJit suggestion**, i rectify my code but i am getting this [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FaLj.png) not desired one which above attached. View background colour causing problem. how can i achieve that??

Comment: Why do you want to use clipping? Wouldn't it be easier to just draw the 5 lines required instead?

Comment: i tried but  unable to find in ui.Could you please help in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using `_pendingView` i.e. your `UIView`, origin for drawing path but layer will placed inside the `_pendingView`, so because of this you are not getting proper output.

For more clarification you can go through the below code

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
//    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
//    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(15, _vwArrow.frame.size.height/2)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, _vwArrow.frame.size.height)];
[path closePath];

//    [path fill ];
//    [path stroke];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
shapeLayer.frame = _vwArrow.bounds;
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = self.view.backgroundColor.CGColor;
//    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

//    _vwArrow.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
[_vwArrow.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: could please help in that ?

Comment: did you make changes in the code, according to answer?

Comment: yes, inplace of _vwArrow , i used _pendingView. And pendingView has a background color.

Comment: in image it looks color have alpha value below 1. Please check it

Comment: yes, background color of cell have 0.25 alpha. Thanks alot buddy.